# Django clear form field after a submit form. form create in forms.py

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-formtools

I tried a lot but could not find a solution
I also try javascript but could not find a solution

```
def postPage(request, id):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=id)
    showcomment = Comment.objects.filter(postby = id)
    form = commentForm()
    form = commentForm(request.POST)
    form.instance.postby = post   
    if form.is_valid():
       form.save()
       form = commentForm()
       redirect('postpage', id=post.sno)
       context = {'post':post, 'form':form, 'showcomment':showcomment}
       return render(request, 'blog/postpage.html', context)
```

> form = commentForm() Only the field shows blank But the data is
> submitted when we refresh

HTML File

```
form action="." method="POST">
{{form}}
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It looks like the function is not properly indented.Furthermore it is not entirely clear for me what you aim to achieve.

Comment: Can you give some more details on what you're trying and what goes wrong

Comment: when user click submit button then clear form field

Comment: The form field does not become empty after submitting the form

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new `form` immediately before you render the form. Note however that by creating a new form, the errors will dissapear. Furthermore for forms that are not that small, it is often wanted behavior to return a (partially) filled in form, such that the user can continue editing:

```
def postPage(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = commentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.postby_id = id
            form.save()
            redirect('postpage', id=post.sno)
   form = commentForm()
   showcomment = Comment.objects.filter(postby=id)
   context = {'post': post, 'form': form, 'showcomment': showcomment}
   return render(request, 'blog/postpage.html', context)
```